# What happens when you use mockStatic() on a non-static class?

Tags: java, powermock

I'm reading some test code that calls `mockStatic(MyClass.class)`, but `MyClass` is neither `static` nor does it contain `static` methods.

Are there other benefits of using `mockStatic()`?

Not sure if related, but PowerMock is also used in the test code.

Comment: It can also be used for a lot of configuration for classes or methods that are very complicated to test. Github link:  https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/9bd63da355f0ab862880e72976770ae44851f6c7/api/mockito/src/main/java/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.java

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I just reply here..

According to its latest documentation, Mockito doesnt have mockStatic(), so I think this comes from PowerMock. You can go in to the method declaration to see at least the method comes from which module.

For Powermock, the class inside mockStatic() doesnt have to be static class. The goal of mockStatic is to mock the static method. See here: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic